# pass current page url to iframe address

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Hello I'm trying to get something like

```
<iframe src="http://anydomain.com/frame.php?ref=http://currentpageurl.com/dir"></iframe>
```

I'm using this HTML

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(window.location.pathname);
</script>
.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" />
```

I'm getting this error in console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
GET http://localhost/%3Cscript%20type=/
```

Comment: this because your irames src is `http://localhost/
<script type=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a purely JS solution which seems to be what you're going for (though I'd recommend doing this during server-side rendering instead) I'd do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
      iframe.src = 'http://anydomain.com/frame.php?ref=' + window.location.href; // if you just want the path change `href` to `pathname`
      document.body.appendChild(iframe); // insert the element wherever you want in the page
</script>
```